# Why is the color of my text not changing?

Tags: html, css

I am desperately trying to change the color of "hero-text" in CSS.
It does not work (unless I style in the HTML). Google Dev Tools did not help me find out why. I just need to know why.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  }

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navbar */


.sm-logo{
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
margin-left: 20px;
color: white;

}


.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}


.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}



.nav-links {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

.burger {
  display:  none;
  }



/* Hero image */


#hero-image {

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/hero.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  };


/* Hero text */

#hero-overlay {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  };




/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="hero-image">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
              <div class="sm-logo">
                <a>Christine Grän</a>
              </div>
              
              <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Über Mich</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Bücher</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Termine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
              
              <div class="burger">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
              </div>
            </nav>
            
            <div id="hero-overlay">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="hero-text"> Lorem ipsum......</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help. I want to learn from this but it has been hours and Id love to move on to something else.

This is my js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6rqy85bx/7/

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

For that we need to select `.hero-text` in CSS and apply `color` property.

Also I have removed certain unwanted `;` in your CSS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  }

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navbar */


.sm-logo{
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
margin-left: 20px;
color: white;

}


.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}


.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}



.nav-links {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

.burger {
  display:  none;
  }



/* Hero image */


#hero-image {

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/hero.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  }


/* Hero text */

#hero-overlay {
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  }




/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
/*Hero-Text*/
.hero-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="hero-image">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
              <div class="sm-logo">
                <a>Christine Grän</a>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Über Mich</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Bücher</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Termine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="burger">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="hero-overlay">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="hero-text"> Lorem ipsum......</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the `hero-text` class at all, so I'm guessing there is a style on that class or element that overrides what you do.
This should target the text:

```
.hero-text {
color: white;
font-size: 100px;
}
```

If this still doesn't work, try `#hero-overlay .hero-text {}`

Comment: Its really not that I tried it and it just wont work. I also can't target hero-overlay at all.

Comment: This answer is wrong because you has errors in your css, remove ; after }

Comment: Yes I had copied OP's code and failed to remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  }

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navbar */


.sm-logo{
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
margin-left: 20px;
color: white;

}


.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}


.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}



.nav-links {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

.burger {
  display:  none;
  }



/* Hero image */


#hero-image {

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/hero.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  };


/* Hero text */

#hero-overlay {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  };

#hero-overlay .hero-text{
  color:white
 };



/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation. Please see [answer].

Comment: Please try to add  #hero-overlay .hero-text{color: white;} in your css code as shown

Comment: Your _answer_ should have some explanation. It should not be down here in a comment.